# How to rename the views tabs in user accounts

Tags: users

How do i rename the "view" tab in the user accounts? I want to rename it to Profile. Am using drupal 7 and the zen sub-theme. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module gives you a user interface to do that.